# Getting error when I tries to use an array of multiple subnet in terraform

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, terraform, tuples, subnet

When I am trying to use multiple subnets it gives me the following error:
[image]

And these are the tf related blocks:
[image]

[image]

Please help

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the conceppt of `element` function. Here,

```
element(var.subnet_public1_cidr_block, 3)
```

selects cidr of index-3(fourth element) but there is just 0, 1 and 2 ... So, to choose first index of `subnet_public1_cidr_block = ["10.0.128.0/20", "10.0.128.0/20", "10.0.128.0/20"]` use this instead:

```
element(var.subnet_public1_cidr_block, 0)
```

This will use first cidr value.
OR,

you can dynamically use count variable as:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_public1" {
    ...
    count = 3
    cidr_block = element(var.subnet_public1_cidr_block, count.index)
    map_public_ip_on_launch = "true"
    availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
    ...
}
```